# How to avoid store password in plaintext in glassfish ldap configuration file?

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish, ldap, glassfish-3

*Context*: I developed a webapp using jsp and installed it using Glassfish 3.1, I'm successfully validating my users, by asking them their username and password, to LDAP using an XML file in my server, which looks like this:

security-config.xml:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">     
<security:ldap-authentication-provider 
        group-search-base="OU=OFN_Users,OU=_OFN"        
        user-search-filter="(sAMAccountName={0})" 
        server-ref="ldapLocal"
        role-prefix="ROLE_">       
</security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager> 
...
<security:ldap-server url="ldap://X.X.X.X:X/DC=X,DC=X,DC=X" 
         id="ldapLocal" 
        manager-dn="user@domain" 
        manager-password="PASSWORD"
/>
...
```

*Question*: Is there a way to avoid having the PASSWORD stored in plaintext in the security-config.xml configuration file?

Thanks.

*EDIT:* If there is a way in which the password is not stored in external files at all, I'd also like to know about it...

Comment: My guess is the security is meant to be applied to the file, not within the file.  In other words, this config file is probably meant to be kept in a safe location with no permissions for anybody who shouldn't be authorized.  That said, I'll be anxious to hear if there _IS_ an answer to your question.

Comment: @jahory Yeah, I also think that file permission should be enough, but actually the client (stake holder) has this requirement. I really hope there is an answer...